# _popen crash[Windows - C]

Tags: c, windows, sockets, popen

Im very much a newcomer to C (in fact to all compiled languages), below you will see my horrible code where I try to receive a command and later I wish to execute it (not implemented yet).

I grapped the example code from Microsoft on the _popen function and modified it (ever so slightly) but for some reason this crashes my program after it has received the command. If I move this block of code above the command receiver part it works just fine. Am I overwriting another memory address or something?

If you need the server (written in python) just let me know. Hope you can help a noob in need.

```
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>

int sendall(int sock, char *message, unsigned int size);
int connect(char address[], short port);
char* recvall(int sock, unsigned int *msgsize);


int main(){
    char address[] = "127.0.0.1";
    short port = 1234;
    int wait = 5000;

    //Connect back
    int sock = 1;
    printf("Connecting...\n");
    sock = connect(address, port);
    while(sock == 1){
        WSACleanup();
        Sleep(wait);
        sock = connect(address, port);
    }

    printf("Succesfully conneted\n");

    char test[] = "ABCDEFGH";
    sendall(sock,test, 8);

    unsigned int msgsize;
    char *msg = recvall(sock,&msgsize);


    printf("%s\n", msg);
    printf("%d\n", msgsize);


    //RUN COMMAND

    char   psBuffer[128];
    FILE   *pPipe;


    printf("There\n");

    if( (pPipe = _popen( "ipconfig", "rt" )) == NULL )
        exit( 1 );

    printf("Out\n");

    while(fgets(psBuffer, 128, pPipe)){
        printf(psBuffer);
    }


    if (feof( pPipe)){
        printf( "\nProcess returned %d\n", _pclose( pPipe ) );
    }else{
        printf( "Error: Failed to read the pipe to the end.\n");
    }

    //RUN COMMAND END 

    Sleep(10000);
    return 0;
}

int sendall(int sock, char *message, unsigned int size){

    //Send size packet
    char sizepacket[12];
    sprintf (sizepacket, "%012u",size);
    send(sock, sizepacket, 12, 0);

    //Send data
    unsigned int left = size;
    unsigned int offset = 0;
    while(left>0){
        if(left<1024){
            send(sock, (message+offset), left, 0);
            left = 0;
        }else{
            send(sock, (message+offset), 1024, 0);
            offset = offset + 1024;
            left = left - 1024;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

char* recvall(int sock, unsigned int *size){
    char *message;

    //Get size packet
    char sizebuff[24];
    memset (&sizebuff,0,24);
    recv(sock, sizebuff, 12, 0);
    *size = atoi(sizebuff);

    //Alloc space for message
    message = (char*)  malloc(*size + 1);
    memset(message,0,1024);

    //Get data
    unsigned int left = *size;
    unsigned int offset = 0;
    while(left>0){
        if(left<1024){
            recv(sock, (message+offset), left, 0);
            left = 0;
        }else{
            recv(sock, (message+offset), 1024, 0);
            offset = offset + 1024;
            left = left - 1024;
        }
    }
    return message;
}



int connect(char address[], short port){
    int returnvalue;

    WSADATA wsaData;

    returnvalue = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,2), &wsaData);
    if(returnvalue != 0){
        return 1;
    }

    int sock;
    sock = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
    if(sock == 0){
        return 1;
    }


    //Create struct
    struct sockaddr_in clientService;
    clientService.sin_family = AF_INET;
    clientService.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(address);
    clientService.sin_port = htons(port);


    returnvalue = connect(sock, (SOCKADDR*) &clientService, sizeof(clientService));
    if (returnvalue != 0){
        closesocket(sock);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }

    return sock;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your popen doesn't appear to depend upon your socket communication.

Please describe the message your server sends (hexdump?)

Please look at your recvall() function.  You read 12 bytes from the socket, convert it to int, and malloc that many bytes, you store that into *size, and then you memset the message buffer (just malloc'ed) for size 1024.  You then receive a message into a buffer but place no guards to ensure you don't overrun the end of message[*size].

```
int main(){
    //...
    unsigned int msgsize;
    char *msg = recvall(sock,&msgsize);
    printf("%d\n", msgsize);
    printf("%s\n", msg);
    return 0;
}

char* recvall(int sock, unsigned int *size){
    char *message;
    //Get size packet
    char sizebuff[24];
    memset (&sizebuff,0,24);
    recv(sock, sizebuff, 12, 0);
    *size = atoi(sizebuff);
    printf("size: %d\n",*size);fflush(stdout);
    //Alloc space for message
    message = (char*)  malloc(*size + 1);
    memset(message,0,1024); //why 1024? why not *size?
    //Get data
    unsigned int left = *size;
    unsigned int offset = 0;
    while(left>0){
        if(left<1024){
            recv(sock, (message+offset), left, 0);
            left = 0;
        }else{
            recv(sock, (message+offset), 1024, 0); //why 1024?
            offset = offset + 1024; //again, why 1024?, this is > 1024
            left = left - 1024;
        }
    }
    return message;
}
```

Comment: I feel soo stupid... Sucking at something is the first step I guess. You were right about the first 1024 - the last ones is because I receive the message in 1024 byte chunks, it compiles perfectly now though. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Your example wouldn't compile on my system because you have two versions of the `connect()` function--your local call and the system version, called from within your local `connect()` function itself on this line:

```
returnvalue = connect(sock, (SOCKADDR*) &clientService, sizeof(clientService));
```

Try changing your local version to a different name, e.g. `xconnect()`.  I'm surprised your compiler allowed this.

Comment: Although it is tagged as C, the OP likely compiled the program as C++, in which case that would not be a problem (the two connect functions have different signatures).

Comment: @Mark Wilkins -- Thanks.  You are probably right.  I thought about that, but I didn't see any "this-is-obviously-C++" syntax in the code, plus the OP claimed to be using C (though is an admitted novice).